# Inserting items in listview to database C#

Tags: c#

```
   for (int i = 0; i <= ListView1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
                {

                    string cd = "Insert Into ProductSold(BillNo,DishName,DishRate,Quantity,TotalAmount) VALUES (@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5)";
                    cmd = new OleDbCommand(cd);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d1", txtBillNo.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d2", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d3", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d4", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d5", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    clear();


                }
```

i want to insert all the items in listview to database i insert 2 items but only 1 items are added help please?

Comment: u can use foreach loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use foreach loop ..

Just try this.

```
 foreach (ListViewItem l in Listview1.Items)
{
  string cd = "Insert Into ProductSold(BillNo,DishName,DishRate,Quantity,TotalAmount) VALUES (@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5)";
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(cd);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d1", txtBillNo.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d2", l.SubItems[1].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d3", l.SubItems[2].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d4", l.SubItems[3].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d5", l.SubItems[4].Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Comment: i think u are right, its clearing the connection content, which may lead to close the connection

Comment: Thanks sir! it worked :) Thankyouu very much! commended

Comment: Can u give me some advice about this sir? :)

Comment: listview1.item is an object, you are trying to call it in string, So for that purpose foreach helps you to call the string each time which is present in ur listview..

Comment: and as @RichardSchneider said clear will close the connection , so it wont loop again..

Comment: Thanks you very much sir. Someday i will become like you or even surpass you in answering every question lol.

Comment: Thanks again @Anirudh Godbless sir! :)

Comment: It's the good way BUT if one error goes before the end of the loop you will have partial insertion to your database, for multiple insert queries I suggest you to use a transaction then if an error occur you can cancel all insertions, this is more secure for your database

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `clear()` does but most likely it is closing the connection or doing some other side effect.  I would move the `clear()` to outside of the `for` loop.

```
const string cd = @"Insert into
  ProductSold (BillNo,DishName,DishRate,Quantity,TotalAmount) 
  VALUES (@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5)";
var cmd = new OleDbCommand(cd) { Connection = con };

foreach (var l in Listview1.Items)
{
   cmd.Parameters.Clear();
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d1", txtBillNo.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d2", l.SubItems[1].Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d3", l.SubItems[2].Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d4", l.SubItems[3].Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d5", l.SubItems[4].Text);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
clear();
```

Comment: Yes sir you're right. The problem is the clear. commended for that.